# PostgreSQL: Find records with single quotes

Tags: postgresql

I have identified records in one of our tables with TWO single quotes.

So the record field appears as: `''`

What SQL could I utilize to find all the record occurrences with `''`
I have tried `'%'` and also `'%''%'` with no success.

Answer (score 2):

`'%''%'`  will look for entries with a one single quote (as a single quote is escaped by doubling it). If you want to search for two single quotes, you need 4 quotes (because of the escaping), e.g.:

```
where the_column like '%''''%'
```

alternatively you can use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid the escaping

```
where the_column like $$%''%$$
```

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for your response. I tried BOTH of these solutions and when the query completes I get no query results at all; however when I view the Top 100 rows I can see the one column I'm investigation definitely has ''.  Then I also tried  `` thinking the ticks were not rendering properly. I'm wondering that the character font in the table column may not match the key board tick I am entering in pgAdmin.

Comment: @user9491577: this will work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd08e1bf0ea646f9882ad3569b7e9289 if it doesn't work for you, then those aren't "real" single quotes